# Setting "Credentials set" for hyperledger Composer card

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

What are the step to create card with credentails as "Credentials set" hyperledger composer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in Playground -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/playground/id-cards-playground#manually-creating-a-business-network-card

From the CLI -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/id-cards-playground#creating-a-business-network-card-from-component-files

Programatically - as shown by the example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#card-api-errors--resolutions - see the section from the line

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#card-api-errors--resolutions

onwards.

The important thing is that if you're using an enrol secret, you should connect() or ping the network first, so that the identity is activated and its credentials (certificate/key) can be downloaded to 'his/her' wallet (from where it can be exported and shared if that is the requirement). You can use it in Playground, or export it (eg. for importing into the REST API wallet, when interacting with the business network from the Composer REST APIs)

Comment: you are saying that Once a card is created, the credentials default set as **one time only** and how to create public/private certificate for hyperledger composer

Comment: saying: once enroled, the blockchain identity is activated ( have the public/private key and becomes part of a business network card).  Generally speaking, that identity lives until such time as it expires or is revoked by the CA configured in Fabric. The CA you configure issues certs/keys ; Composer interacts with it to issue identities via Composer, but you can create the cert/key independently (or they may already exist) and create the business network card with those manually, as instructed in the docs.

Comment: Ok, imagine i have created a card as peer admin(only with password no certificate issues) and after closing network. Then I try to ping the card  as`composer network ping --card newlyCardyyy@hlfv11`  it returns as followes `Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]`. What must be done to correct the error.

Comment: The PeerAdmin is not part of the business network (chaincode) itself.  PeerAdmin is a user role with administrative privileges (at a Fabric level) for the organization from which the certificate (ie credentials) was generated. This role has the ability to add/remove peers, deploy chaincode, create and join channels, etc. on behalf of that organization. Hence why your ping doesn't work. Read more on participants and identities - within a business network - here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities

Comment: Thanx for the comment. I will try to work out the problem.

Comment: Can you suggest me some link or videos to create a card and deploy in composer without this error `Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]`. I even tryed to create a card in playground but still i am getting this errors. So pls help me.... and the composer version is `0.20`.